# creating sequences in ML

Tags: sequence, ml

```
 datatype 'a seq = Nil | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a seq);

 fun head(Cons(x,_)) = x | head Nil = raise EmptySeq;
 fun tail(Cons(_,xf)) = xf() | tail Nil = raise EmptySeq;

 datatype direction = Back | Forward;
 datatype 'a bseq =   bNil 
                    | bCons of 'a * (direction -> 'a bseq); 

 fun bHead(bCons(x,_)) = x | bHead bNil = raise EmptySeq; 
 fun bForward(bCons(_,xf)) = xf(Forward) | bForward bNil = raise EmptySeq; 
 fun bBack(bCons(_,xf)) = xf(Back) | bBack bNil = raise EmptySeq;
```

so after all those definitions. here's what I'm trying to do. I need to take 2 sequences and make them into 1 sequence that I can move Farward and Back on. 
for example if 1 sequence is 0123... and 2 is -1-2-3-4..., I get -4-3-2-10123.
my current location must always be the first element of the sequence going "up".
this is what I've tried to do:

```
 (*************************************************************)
 local
     fun append_aux (Nil, yq) = yq
        |append_aux (Cons(x,xf), yq) = Cons(x,fn() => append_aux(xf(),yq))
     fun append(t,yq) = append_aux(Cons(t,fn() => Nil),yq)
 in
     fun seq2bseq (Cons(x,xrev)) (Cons(y,ynorm)) = bCons(y,fn Farward => seq2bseq      (append(y,Cons(x,xrev))) (ynorm())
                                                        |Back    => seq2bseq (xrev()) (append(x,Cons(y,ynorm)))) 
   |seq2bseq  (_) (_) = bNil                                              
 end;
```

but I get an error "match redundant"  for the "Back" match and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Read the case on the line before the "Back" match *very carefully*.

Comment: yeah, someone pointed it out to me, I spelled Forward wrong